# Need to draw a line graph using JQuery after reading x and y values from an array.

Tags: jquery

My values are of the form:

```
arr = [{10:20:00, 75.35}, {10:21:00,80.30}, {10:22:00, 78.54},...}
```

Want to plot a Line graph with these values. I am a newbie to JQuery. Can anyone help?

Comment: Well you can use a jquery plugin to do a graph. Take a look at some of them: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/ some of them are not free and you have to pay but if it solve your problem with qualitiy, I think it is ok to pay. You also can google a nice plugin. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used http://www.highcharts.com to draw different kinds of charts in the past. Have a look at their demo page at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ and 'Edit in jfiddle' to get a grip on how to draw the graph with your data.

Answer (score 1):

jquery charts example http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/jquery-charts/

you can also use jqplot for drawing graphs
http://www.jqplot.com/